# Splitting triplicates into duplicates

Tags: r, combinations

I am wanting to split sets of triplicate results into the three possible duplicates.

If the initial set is

```
    A   B   C
1 122 106 114
2 110 122 110
```

I want to transform it into

```
    A   B
1 122 106
2 122 114
3 106 114
4 110 122
5 110 110
6 122 110
```

The combn function will do it line by line but I cannot figure out how to apply it across the full dataframe (which can be quite large, I only used two lines for demonstration purposes.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Use `lapply()` to apply your `combn` for each row of the data
2. Use `rbind` to combine the results
3. Make use of the magic of `do.call` to combine the list created by steps 1 and 2.

In one line of code:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(nrow(dat)), function(i)t(combn(dat[i, ], 2))))
    [,1] [,2]
[1,] 122  106 
[2,] 122  114 
[3,] 106  114 
[4,] 110  122 
[5,] 110  110 
[6,] 122  110
```

Comment: Almost.  It has duplicated line 1 and not done line 2.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't change the 1 to an i.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. I'll use `data.table`s to illustrate the concept. But it should be fairly straightforward using data.frames as well.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
require(reshape2) ## for melt generic
setDT(dat) 
r1 = melt(dat, id="A", value.name="B")[, variable := NULL]
rbindlist(list(r1, dat[, list(B,C)]))
#      A   B
# 1: 122 106
# 2: 110 122
# 3: 122 114
# 4: 110 110
# 5: 106 114
# 6: 122 110
```

Comment: I'd guess, that this is the by far the fastest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over all rows as suggested by Andrie, you can also iterate over all combinations returned by `combn`:

```
d <- read.table(text="A   B   C
1 122 106 114
2 110 122 110")

l <- apply(combn(3, 2), 2, function(x) setNames(d[x], c("A", "B")))
do.call(rbind, l)

##      A   B
## 1  122 106
## 2  110 122
## 11 122 114
## 21 110 110
## 12 106 114
## 22 122 110
```

This is probably faster than iterating over all rows. The function used in `apply` returns the columns of `d` currently of interest, and reassigns column names. Inspect `l` to see what's happening under the hood.